# setTimeout() callback in multiple $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback, settimeout

I know that has many examples but in my example I don't understand how do that.

I have to `setTimeout()` function and I need to run second `timeout` when first ends.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ucvvegay/)

```js
var title = $(".form-title").attr("data-title");
var fname = $(".form-name").attr("data-name");

$.each(title.split(''), function(i, letter) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.form-title').html($('.form-title').html() + letter);
  }, 100 * i);
});

$.each(fname.split(''), function(i, letter) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.form-name label:nth-of-type(1)').html($('.form-name label:nth-of-type(1)').html() + letter);
  }, 100 * i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="form-title" data-title="Dear Concept Studio,"></h2>
<p class="form-name" data-name="Hello, I'm">
  <label></label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any. But you can use `counter` to call the function when the counter reaches the last element.

What I've done:

1. Created a `counter` variable
2. Moved the code to show the animation of second string in another separate function
3. Incremented the `counter` after each character is appended
4. Checked if `counter` is equal to the `length` of the string, if it is then call the function that'll animate the second string.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ucvvegay/1/)

```js
var title = $(".form-title").attr("data-title");
var fname = $(".form-name").attr("data-name");

var counter = 0;
$.each(title.split(''), function(i, letter) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.form-title').html($('.form-title').html() + letter);

    ++counter === title.length && animateSecond();
  }, 100 * i);
});

function animateSecond() {
  $.each(fname.split(''), function(i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.form-name label:nth-of-type(1)').html($('.form-name label:nth-of-type(1)').html() + letter);
    }, 100 * i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="form-title" data-title="Dear Concept Studio,"></h2>

<p class="form-name" data-name="Hello, I'm TJ. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, corporis, omnis? Maiores alias expedita, quis, aliquam, assumenda deserunt molestias maxime non, natus cupiditate illo harum. Amet autem inventore quis adipisci!">
  <label></label>
</p>
```